# Showing an infoWindow immediately after a Layer query succeeded

Tags: javascript, dojo, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a web application, where a user can switch between some 160-ish layers. Most of them are Feature Layers, but some are of type `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`.

I need to be able to query those layers the same as I do with FeatureLayers: by clicking on any point on the map and displaying an infowindow.

This is my code so far (removed some bits for clarity):

```
executeQueryTask: function(evt, scope) {
    //"this" is the map object in this context, so we pass in the scope from the caller, 
    //which will enable us to call the layer and map object and all the other precious widget properties 
    scope.map.graphics.clear();
    scope.map.infoWindow.hide();
    //we create a new Circle and set its center at the mappoint. The radius will be 20 meters
    //default unit is meters. 
    var circle = new Circle({
        /*...*/
    });
    // draw the circle to the map:
    var circleGraphic = new Graphic(circle, /*...*/));

    scope.map.graphics.add(circleGraphic);

    var queryTask = new QueryTask(scope.layer.layer.url + "/" + scope.layer.layer.visibleLayers[0]);
    var query = new Query();
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["*"];
    query.geometry = circle.getExtent();
    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate().setTitle("");
    queryTask.execute(query, function(resultSet) {
        array.forEach(resultSet.features, function(feature) {
            var graphic = feature;
            graphic.setSymbol(/*...*/));
            //Set the infoTemplate.
            // graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
            //Add graphic to the map graphics layer.
            scope.map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.attributes);
            scope.map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint, scope.map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
            scope.map.graphics.add(graphic);
        });
    });
},
```

The key point is insise the `queryTask.execute` callback. If I uncomment and use `graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);` the result is colored and upon a second click an infoWindow pops up. 
There are 2 issues with this approach:

1. 2 clicks are needed
2. I am unable to click on PolyLines and Points twice, so no infowindow pops up here.

This is why I added a circle to get a 100m buffer in radius to my click. Now I want to immediatly return an infoWindow. 
At this point I'm struggeling to successfully create an Info Window, which is immediately displayed.

Currently the line `scope.map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.attributes);` throws an error `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

How can I create that Info Window?

Answer (score 1):

I found a suitable approach, which leaves room for improvements. But this is for another iteration.

```
 //create a new FeatureLayer object
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(scope.layer.layer.url + "/" + scope.layer.layer.visibleLayers[0], {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
    infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}"),
    outFields: ["*"]
});
//we create a new Circle and set its center at the mappoint. The radius will be 20 meters
//default unit is meters. 
var circle = new Circle({/*...*/});

// draw the circle to the map:
var circleGraphic = new Graphic(circle, /*...*/));
scope.map.graphics.add(circleGraphic);

var lQuery = new Query();
lQuery.returnGeometry = true;
lQuery.geometry = circle.getExtent();
featureLayer.queryFeatures(lQuery, function(results) {
    array.forEach(results.features, function(feature) {
        var graphic = feature;
        graphic.setSymbol(/*...*/));

        //now that we have the feature, we need to select it
        var selectionQuery = new Query();
        selectionQuery.geometry = feature.geometry;
        featureLayer.selectFeatures(selectionQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW)
            .then(function(selectedFeatures) {
                console.info("selection complete", selectedFeatures);
                if (!selectedFeatures.length) {
                    return;
                }
                scope.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(selectedFeatures);
                scope.map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint, "upperright");
            });
    });
});
```

The change here is, that we are no longer using a `QueryTask`, but create a new FeatureLayer object in selection mode, using the url and id of the visible layer.

The second noteworthy change is, that we no longer set the content of the infoWindow, but instead set selected features using `infoWindow.setFeatures(selectedFeatures)`. Setting the content of an infoWindow, but not selecting features, hides the action list of the info window, this hinders you to zoom to an object or perform other custom operations. 
In addition, this enables you( or me ) to view multiple results in the infoWindow, instead of just one.

Comment: that's helpful Great !